# Where is the multi-threading comming from?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, audio

I have a multi-threading problem. A well placed @synchronized{} around the bit of code where I was sorting and modifying a NSOrderedSet seemed to clean up the problem in the portion where I was reading it back. My problem now is trying to figure out where my other thread is coming from so I can better understand my code. Do either of these snippets cause a new thread?

```
CADisplayLink* gameTimer;
gameTimer = [CADisplayLink
             displayLinkWithTarget:self
             selector:@selector(updateDisplay:)];

[gameTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

and/or does this start a thread?

```
 AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
 callbackStruct.inputProc = PerformThru;
 callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = &_effectState;

 AudioUnitSetProperty(      _effectState.rioUnit, 
                            kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                            bus0, 
                            &callbackStruct, 
                            sizeof(callbackStruct);
 AudioOutputUnitStart(_effectState.rioUnit);
```

I'm guessing the later because in the PerformThru function I start seeing debug messages like

```
   Object 0x682ec20 of class __NSOrderedSetM autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

But, in main I have @autoreleasepool.. so I'm guessing there is something causing another thread.

Answer (score 2):

The audio unit render callback will be called in a private (to Core Audio) background thread. You can see this by putting a breakpoint in PerformThru() and noting that the stack frame where the debugger stops is not in the main thread/queue.

Comment: ok.. that makes sense, I was close to that deduction.  As a follow up question, is it appropriate then to wrap the contents of PerformThru in a @autoreleasepool{}?  Is wrapping the portion where I am modifying a NSMutableOrderedSet in @synchronized{} appropriate (since I was having problems with reading the Set on the main thread)?  Or, are these potentially problematic approaches for some reason?

Comment: Yes, `@autoreleasepool` is a good idea. You haven't posted enough code for me to say for sure, but assuming you're talking about putting `@synchronized` in the render callback, `@synchronized` is probably a bad idea. That function needs to run quickly and not block or you risk audio drop outs. Waiting on a lock is likely to cause exactly that problem. See http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/why-coreaudio-is-hard.html for more.

Comment: yes... I was meaning @ synchronized in the render callback.  I tried @ synchronized in the main thread where I am reading the data I am writing in the render callback, and it caused some nice havoc as I had almost expected (but at least I fixed my crashing problem).  Thanks for the responses, I at least now understand where to focus on untangling this problem.